# Getting NoSuchElementException using Scanner class to read Standard.In after reading in an EOF

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, eof

So, first off, this is homework, albeit not mine. It's my brother-in-law's. He asked me for help since I do computers, but I only work in C++. He's reading in keyboard input into a file using `System.in` until he gets an `EOF`. Afterwards, he creates an instance of `Scanner` and calls `nextLine` on the instance to try to get a `filename` and gets a `NoSuchElementException`. According to Javadoc, that means there's no input to be received, which seems like an odd thing to get back when using `System.in` and typing on the keyboard. My suspicion is that the `EOF` character is somehow not getting consumed. His code is due at midnight tonight and he's got everything else done (I advised him to use a dummy filename and to come back to the problem).

Here is his code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
        createFile();
        readFile();
    }

public static void createFile()
{

    //Variables
    InputStream istream;
    PrintStream ostream;
    istream = System.in;
    ostream = System.out;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lastEntry = 0;
    final int EOF = -1;


    //Asks user for filename.
    try
    {
        String fileName;
        System.out.println("Please enter the filename of the file you want to open: ");
        fileName = keyboard.next();

        //Creates specified file.           
        File currentFile = new File(fileName);

        //Checks if file already exists.
        while(currentFile.exists())
        { 
            System.out.println(fileName + " already exists");
            System.out.println("Error: To prevent tis file from being overwritten please enter another file name");
            fileName = keyboard.nextLine();         
        }

        //Asks user for information they want stored in file.           
        try 
        {
            ostream = new PrintStream(fileName);
            System.out.println("Please enter what you would like to put in the file and press Ctrl+Z when finished: ");

            //Writes information to file.
            try
            {
                while((lastEntry = istream.read()) != EOF)
                ostream.write(lastEntry);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: " +e.getMessage());
            }

        }           
        catch(Exception f)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " +e.getMessage());
        }
    }   

    finally
    {
    }

}   

public static void readFile()   
{
        InputStream input;
        PrintStream output;
        output = System.out;
        int lastEntry = 0;
        final int EOF = -1;
        Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Asks user for filename.
        String newFile;
        System.out.println("Please enter the filename of the file you want to open: ");

            newFile = keyboard2.next();
    }       
}
```

He's getting the `NoSuchElementException` error on the `newFile = keyboard2.next()` line. I've browsed my way through a bunch of examples and found people posting about having this problem, but I've yet to find a solution, so I figured I'd put my (dubious) reputation here on the line for him. Anyone know how he can get this to work?

Comment: have you tried kerboard2.nextLine(); ???

Comment: above code goes into the infinite loop buddy,ctrl+z wont let you come out of the first function,i guess first you need to rectify that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EOF character on the console means ... end of file.  That's why Scanner method calls are throwing `NoSuchElementException`.

There in no way for a pure Java application to read anything after the EOF marker.

---

> There's no way to clear it?

Not in pure Java.  In theory you could do this from native code, but I doubt that would be acceptable to the teacher.

Comment: There's no way to clear it? Part of it is that he has to take in an arbitrary amount of input. The teacher's examples use Ctrl-Z to end the input, but his homework assignment has him ask for one more filename.

Comment: Ultimately, he went through and checked the input for a string literal ("EOF", actually) and he's got his code working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop here:

```
    //Checks if file already exists.
    while(currentFile.exists())
    { 
        System.out.println(fileName + " already exists");
        System.out.println("Error: To prevent tis file from being overwritten please enter another file name");
        fileName = keyboard.nextLine();         
    }
```

`currentFile` isn't being updated with the new file name.

As for the actual problem at hand, Stephen is right, once you hit the `EOF` in the  `createFile` method, you can't get more input from the keyboard.  In that respect, you're right that the `EOF` isn't consumed.  You'll need to use some other sort of signal to indicate the end of the input text (the literal string `"EOF"`, perhaps).

Answer (score 1):

I was reading your code and I think I found a bug completely unrelated to your question:

```
        //Checks if file already exists.
        while(currentFile.exists())
        { 
            System.out.println(fileName + " already exists");
            System.out.println("Error: To prevent this file from being overwritten please enter another file name");
            fileName = keyboard.nextLine();         
        }
```

If `currentFile.exists()`, you're going to get an infinite loop because you don't update `currentFile` in your loop, just `fileName`.

Although this may not be your primary concern at the moment, you should still fix it to avoid running into the problem in the future.

---

**To address your problem:
He can catch the NoSuchElementException. In his catch statement, he can execute a statement doing whatever he wants to do: exit the method, end the program, anything!**

Comment: Good call. I pasted his original source code, which did have that error, but which he has since fixed.